# pod install fail on command cmd: 'cd ios && pod install && cd

Tags: node.js, react-native, jhipster, ignite-ui

I am new to Jhipster, React and first timer with React Native. Trying to ignite application fails on mentioned command with below output error. I have managed to develop an app using Jhipster+React now trying to develop it's React Native UI using Ignite Jhipster

```
➜  code git:(master) ✗ ignite new vimsmob --boilerplate ignite-jhipster                            
-----------------------------------------------
  (                  )   (                   
  )\ )   (        ( /(   )\ )    *   )       
 (()/(   )\ )     )\()) (()/(  ` )  /(   (   
  /(_)) (()/(    ((_)\   /(_))  ( )(_))  )\  
 (_))    /(_))_   _((_) (_))   (_(_())  ((_) 
 |_ _|  (_)) __| | \| | |_ _|  |_   _|  | __|
  | |     | (_ | | .` |  | |     | |    | _| 
 |___|     \___| |_|\_| |___|    |_|    |___|
-----------------------------------------------

An unfair headstart for your React Native apps.
https://infinite.red/ignite

-----------------------------------------------

 igniting app vimsmob
✔ Generating a React Native client for JHipster apps
✔ Enter the path to your JHipster project root directory: · /Users/shahzad/git/vims/code/vims
Looking for /Users/shahzad/git/vims/code/vims/.yo-rc.json
Found JHipster config file at /Users/shahzad/git/vims/code/vims/.yo-rc.json
✔ Do you want to enable end-to-end tests with Detox? (y/N) · false
Using npm as the package manager
✔ added React Native 0.60.5 in 74.93s
✔ using the JHipster boilerplate
✔ project generated
✔ set up react-native-navigation for iOS/Android
✔ dependencies installed
JHipster config saved to your app's .jhipster folder.
⠙ ▸ running pod installan error occured while installing ignite-jhipster boilerplate.
{ Error: Command failed: cd ios && pod install && cd ..

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'cd ios && pod install && cd ..',
  stderr: '' }
error installing boilerplate
➜  code git:(master) ✗ 

➜  code git:(master) ✗ node -v                        
v10.17.0
➜  code git:(master) ✗ npm -v                         
6.11.3
➜  code git:(master) ✗ react-native -v   
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
➜  vimsmob git:(master) ✗ pwd                                              
/Users/shahzad/git/vims/code/vimsmob
```

Versions:

```
- Ignite JHipster Version: 3.3.1
- `ignite doctor` output:
➜  vimsmob git:(master) ✗ ignite doctor                                   
System
  platform           darwin                                                
  arch               x64                                                   
  cpu                12 cores     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz 
  directory          vimsmob      /Users/shahzad/git/vims/code/vimsmob     

JavaScript
  node               10.17.0      /usr/local/bin/node 
  npm                6.11.3       /usr/local/bin/npm  
  yarn               -            not installed       

Ignite
  ignite-cli         3.3.1                                                                                     /usr/local/bin/ignite                        
  ignite src         build                                                                                     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ignite-cli/build 
  generators         {"entity":"ignite-jhipster","import-jdl":"ignite-jhipster","upgrade":"ignite-jhipster"}                                                

Android
  java               11.0.2       /Users/shahzad/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java 
  android home       -            undefined                                               

iOS
  xcode              -          
  cocoapods          1.8.4        /usr/local/bin/pod
```

Project Directory Tree

```
➜  vimsmob git:(master) ✗ tree -L 3                 
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── vimsmob
    ├── README.md
    ├── android
    │   ├── app
    │   ├── build.gradle
    │   ├── gradle
    │   ├── gradle.properties
    │   ├── gradlew
    │   ├── gradlew.bat
    │   └── settings.gradle
    ├── app
    │   ├── config
    │   ├── modules
    │   ├── navigation
    │   └── shared
    ├── app.json
    ├── babel.config.js
    ├── fastlane
    │   ├── Appfile
    │   ├── Fastfile
    │   └── Matchfile
    ├── ignite
    │   ├── ignite.json
    │   └── plugins
    ├── index.js
    ├── ios
    │   ├── Podfile
    │   ├── Pods
    │   ├── vimsmob
    │   ├── vimsmob-tvOS
    │   ├── vimsmob-tvOSTests
    │   ├── vimsmob.xcodeproj
    │   └── vimsmobTests
    ├── metro.config.js
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── patches
    │   ├── @storybook+react-native+5.2.1.patch
    │   ├── README.md
    │   └── tcomb-form-native+0.6.20.patch
    ├── storybook
    │   ├── addons.js
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── rn-addons.js
    │   └── stories.js
    └── test
        ├── setup.js
        └── spec
```

https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster/blob/v3.3.1/src/boilerplate/index.js line 224 seems to be causing this issue

I tried to update this file with fixed paths in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ignite-jhipster/src/boilerplate/index.js but in project, these changes are not being reflected in generated project.

Comment: Is there a folder called `ios` in your project directory?  Do you have [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) installed?

Comment: Yes cocoapods is installed. I have added project directory tree in the question.

Answer (score 1):

On /Application/Xcode.app --> Make sure your it's Xcode.app. I've done lots of R & D on this. In my case, I had multiple Xcodes on my mac, so I've renamed it to like Xcode 11.4.1.app & Xcode 10.4.app, So I renamed the Xcode 11.4.1.app to Xcode.app, and boom, It's worked!!!